# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment in dictionary

Tags: python

I have a script

```
import shelve
import random
class Worker():
    data = {}
    def __init__(self):
        global data, id_
        id_ = ''
        data = {}
        with shelve.open('WorkerDB') as wdb:
            for key in wdb.keys():
                data[key] = key
                print(data[key])
        check = input('Do you have an id (Yes/No): ')
        if check == 'No':
            self.workType = input('Enter your work: ')
            self.name = input('Enter a name: ')
            self.surname = input('Enter a surname: ')
            self.age = input('How old: ')
            for i in range(8):
                n = round(random.random()*10)
                if(n < 10):
                  id_ += str(n)
                else:
                 id_ += str(n//10)
            print('Your id is {}'.format(id_))
            data[id_] = {'Name': self.name,
                          'Surname': self.surname,
                          'Work': self.workType,
                          'Age': self.age}
        else:
            while id_ == '':
                check = input('Please enter your id: ')
                if check in data.keys():
                    id_ = check
                else:
                    print('This is a wrong id')
    def changeInfo(self):
        print(id_)
        change_part = input('Select which part do you want to change: ')
        change_word = input('Write a new information for {}: '.format(change_part))
        data[id_][change_part] = change_word
    def getInfo(self):
        print(data[id_])
    def loadInfo(self):
        with shelve.open('WorkerDB') as f:
            f[id_] = data[id_]
        f.close()
        print('Loading completed succesfully !!!')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    w1 = Worker()
```

There are two problems:

1. In func `changeInfo(): data[id_][change_part] = change_word` I can't change information because it gives `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`
2. In `getInfo(): print(data[id_])` returns `id_` but I need all keys inside of that `id_`

Comment: It would be easier if you described what is this code supposed to do actually, used sneak_case and type hints, but nevertheless I think that `changeInfo` is going to raise exception "NameError: name 'data' is not defined" or the same error for `id_`.

Comment: Your use of *global* is dubious. What is your intention? As a matter of style (IMHO) do not ask for user input during \_\_init__ Get the values in your main program and pass them to the class constructor

Comment: If you want to share the `data` and `id_` between instances you should use them as class attributes, otherwise use instance attributes and as a rule of thumb do not use global at all unless really necessary (which is super rare in my experience).

Comment: Evidently `data[id_]` is a string, not a dictionary. That would make sense after doing `data[key] = key`.

Answer (score -1):

Your variable `data` is a dictionary whose values contain nested dictionaries. They are formatted as such: `data = {"stringid": {"Name":"name", "Surname":"surname", "Work":"work", "Age":"age"} {"stringid2": ...} }`, but this data structure does not appear to have been actually implemented. The reason you received the string type error when trying to implement the command `data[id_][change_part] = change_word` is that `data[id_][change_part]` is a character of a string that you tried to reassign. You cannot do this.

For example:

```
variable = "banana"

variable[3] = "c"
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

[See example error here](https://discover.cs.ucsb.edu/commonerrors/error/1011.xml)

If your dictionary did successfully update to the format that you wanted (which it did not) then an error would not have occurred.

For example:

```
dictionary = {1 : None} # Create dictionary

dictionary[1] = {2 : "banana"} # Assign a nested dictionary as a value

dictionary[1][2] = "apple" # Reassign the value of a nested dictionary
```

(Runs successfully)

To be honest, your code needs to be cleaned up. You're using global variables unnecessarily and have excessively complicated and relatively difficult-to-read logic. You are getting errors because it is getting increasingly complex to manage your code and you seem to be losing track of what your data structures are doing. Try using helper functions to reduce the clutter and making use of print statements to aid in debugging to make sure that your data is doing exactly what you want it to be doing.